# User Account Control blocks mmc.exe from executing

Tags: windows, windows-10, malware, control-panel, mmc

I was trying to open Device Manager in the control panel.
It gave an error whilst opening. Refer to the image below.And it's my personal laptop.

I need a solution please.To regain full access to my PC .

Could it be malware?

[image: Error described above]

## English translation:

User Account Control

This application has been blocked to protect you.

An administrator has refused that you executed this application. For more information, contact the administrator.

`mmc.exe`

Editor: Unknown
File Origin: Disk Drive on this computer
File Path: `"C:\WINDOWS\system32\mmc.exe" "C:\WINDOWS\system32\services.msc"`

Comment: `mmc` is a legitimate Windows component. Looks like some policy is preventing you from running it.

Comment: but i was able to run it previously .

Comment: Please translate the entire error message into English.

Comment: @Ramhound okay: "This application is blocked for your protection./   An administrator refused the execution of this application. For more information contact the  administrator./   Editor: unknown. File origin : your pc hard drive   Program path : ........'it's already in english' .      "

Comment: @OussaBer - Your screenshot is not in English.  This a personal or corporate PC?  Edit your question instead of submitting comments.  Comments are designed to be temporary.

Comment: Right click on the file and select Properties, see if there is an Unblock button and click it, try install again.

Comment: Is this your computer? Do you have an administrator account you can access?.
Another imnportant thing, is that it says that mmc.exe is Unknown Publisher (When it shold be Microsoft): It is advisable to run a [Malware Scan](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/33evdi/suggested_reading_official_malware_removal_guide/)

Comment: Yes that what  is annoying me. Plus I did scan my PC both with Kaspersky Total Security and MSRT . And nothing is detected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm French, but I agree with those who think it's a matter of permissions: this message means that MMC.exe (Microsoft Management Console) has prevented you from accessing services.msc, the console where you or your admin can administer services.

Your problem comes from the fact that VirtualBox must have been installed on this PC at some point, either by you, or a previous user (in the case of a handover corporate PC), or your sys-admin, whatever.

VirtualBox has been removed from the PC, but it always leaves leftovers, in case you'd want to reinstall it. The services that are eating your CPU cycles are those leftovers.

If this PC is a corporate PC, contact your sys-admin and explain the situation. There are procedures for that sort of problem, namely IT Support can remote-assist you in terminating those processes and get rid of them for good (that's what I do for a living); if they can't, they'll send a tech to your location (could prove difficult at the moment, what with the quarantine and all) to perform some maintenance tasks on the PC, or exchange it for another.

In any case, unless you have a local admin account on this PC, you're screwed, pardon my French.

If you *do* have a local admin account on this PC, then press the Windows key on your keyboard, and type "cmd". When you see "Invite de commande" appear, there are choices on the right to start it as an administrtor. Do so.

Then, once in the command line interface, type "services.msc", and you should be able to open the service management console, and disable all the services pertaining to VirtualBox and/or Vbox.

Comment: Doesn't have to be VirtualBox. If they are not using an administrator account, the administrator might have set UAC consempt prompt to deny all actions, instead of asking por the password, for a regular user.

Comment: The OP first post was about VirtualBox processes eating away at his CPU (on a different post). I advised him to go to services.msc and disable the VirtualBox and Vbox services, then reboot his PC. He must have hit the MMC.exe brickwall while attempting to do so...

Comment: No, it's my personal laptop. And i don't know how to regain my full access to it ?

Comment: Anyway thank you, cause I've killed all VBox and VmWare tasks thanks to your solution. Thanks a lot .

Comment: To all non French-speaking users here: sorry for this aside in the language of Molière... @Oussa: there seems to be a GPO (Group Policy Object; stratégie de groupe) in effect on your PC that prevents you from performing tasks that require administrator privileges. Have you forgotten your admin password? We have no way to know if this PC really belongs to you or not, so no one here will venture an advice as to how to break the GPOs implemented on your PC. This said, you can try a command line with "gpupdate /force" followed by a reboot. It shouldn't change much at first, but you'll start afresh

Comment: @OussaBer Please communicate in English.

Comment: @Didier Will this command line delete my personal files ?

Comment: @DavidPostill the thing is that I can't access my device manager it's showing me the screenshot above. And it's my personal laptop and I'm the administrator. I suspected to be a malware on my device but I ran several tests on Kaspersky and MSRT and nothing has been detected. And I need to regain my full access to my laptop.

Comment: Can you boot in Safe Mode and open Device Manager from there? If there's a malware on your PC, there's a good chance it won't affect it in Safe Mode.